# Replace for decode errors in read_csv

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, python-unicode, bytesio

I am converting a stream to csv using the following code:

```
    req_cont = requests.get(csvfile, headers=headers).content
    inp_df = pd.read_csv(
        BytesIO(req_cont)
    )
```

read_csv is throwing a unicode error. Streams with different encodings appear so I can not guess what is the encoding. How do I replace bytes which can not be decoded in the read_csv function?

Comment: Can you ask request to do the conversion by using `text` (and `StringIO)` instead of `content` (and `BytesIO`)?

Answer (score 0):

You can detect what is the encoding of the stream and as soon as you correctly detect it, try to import full stream

```
lst = ['ascii', 'big5', 'big5hkscs', 'cp037', 'cp273', 'cp424', 'cp437', 'cp500', 'cp720', 'cp737'
       , 'cp775', 'cp850', 'cp852', 'cp855', 'cp856', 'cp857', 'cp858', 'cp860', 'cp861', 'cp862'
       , 'cp863', 'cp864', 'cp865', 'cp866', 'cp869', 'cp874', 'cp875', 'cp932', 'cp949', 'cp950'
       , 'cp1006', 'cp1026', 'cp1125', 'cp1140', 'cp1250', 'cp1251', 'cp1252', 'cp1253', 'cp1254'
       , 'cp1255', 'cp1256', 'cp1257', 'cp1258', 'euc_jp', 'euc_jis_2004', 'euc_jisx0213, ', 'euc_kr'
       , 'gb2312', 'gbk', 'gb18030', 'hz', 'iso2022_jp', 'iso2022_jp_1', 'iso2022_jp_2'
       , 'iso2022_jp_2004', 'iso2022_jp_3', 'iso2022_jp_ext', 'iso2022_kr', 'latin_1', 'iso8859_2'
       , 'iso8859_3', 'iso8859_4', 'iso8859_5', 'iso8859_6', 'iso8859_7', 'iso8859_8', 'iso8859_9'
       , 'iso8859_10', 'iso8859_11', 'iso8859_13', 'iso8859_14', 'iso8859_15', 'iso8859_16', 'johab'
       , 'koi8_r', 'koi8_t', 'koi8_u', 'kz1048', 'mac_cyrillic', 'mac_greek', 'mac_iceland', 'mac_latin2'
       , 'mac_roman', 'mac_turkish', 'ptcp154', 'shift_jis', 'shift_jis_2004', 'shift_jisx0213', 'utf_32'
       , 'utf_32_be', 'utf_32_le', 'utf_16', 'utf_16_be', 'utf_16_le', 'utf_7', 'utf_8', 'utf_8_sig']

for e in lst:
    flag = True
    try:
        # Try with minimal data
        inp_df = pd.read_csv(BytesIO(req_cont), nrow=10)
    except:
        flag = False
    if flag:
        print(encoding, ':\n', inp_df.head())
```